# Celery [ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker' exited with 'exitcode 1'

Tags: python, flask, redis, celery, celery-task

I am trying to use celery==3.1.25 (Python 2.7) to run some expensive tasks separately to my main flask app. However, when I start the celery worker using `celery -A run.celery worker --loglevel=info` the process fails with:

`[ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'Worker' exited with 'exitcode 1'`

Here is my file structure:

```
app/
    __init__.py
    celery_functions.py
    routes.py
    ...
run.py
```

run.py:

```
from app import create_app
from app.config import Config
from celery import Celery

app = create_app('default')
app.app_context().push()

from app.routes import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from config import Config

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
    return app
```

celery_functions.py:

```
import celery

@celery.task(name='celery_functions.archive_repo')
def archive_repo():
    # do something
```

routes.py:

```
from celery_functions import *

@app.route('/archive', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def archive():
    archive_repo.delay()

return ''
```